# Call an ejb entity class from an independent web application (netbeans)

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, netbeans, ejb

I'm making a small webshop application for school in Netbeans. I have a Customer entity class in an EJB module together with a local session bean and a remote session bean.

Next I have an independent web application, which can of course call the remote session bean.

From the application I can call a method in the remote session bean to give me all customers. But what should the session bean return?

- It can return a list of Customers but my application does not know the customer class. Should I add a jar of my ejb module in the application?
- I could return a list of lists with all information of the customers but this is not very nice.
- I have read something [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7588804/java-ee-ejb-entity-web-standalone) about having a Customer interface in the web application but I don't understand how this works.
- Would it help making a Enterprise application and adding both the jar of the ejb module and the war of the web application?

What's the best choice?

(Oh and I'm using wicket as framework, if that has anything to do with this)

EDIT:

So my setup is like this :

- a library containing the entity class and the interface of the remote bean
- a ejb module containing the remote bean and a facade of the entity class, it also has the library above
- a web application: also has the library
- a enterprise application containing the ejb-jar and the war.

It's not working though. When I deploy the ear, I get this error:

```
Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shop2/database/customer/CustomerBeanRemote
```

I'm not sure where to put the persistence file. Now it is in the ejb module. But I don't think this is actually the problem.

Can you maybe guide me through how to make the project. It is the first time I work with EJB and Java EE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a client project contain all your entities and interfaces, and use this project in the EJB module and web project.

In this case you can return a list of customer to the web project by using the remote interface

Of course, you must deploy the ejb project + the client project in an ear project.

Comment: So I put my interfaces and my entities in a java library instead of a client project. The web application already needs that one to know the ejb calls. Is this what you meant or do I need to change anything?

Comment: That didn't work though since the persistance is not in the library. I'll try the client.

Comment: the  java library is the same as client project, and i mean by interface it is the remote interface for your ejb session bean, then when you add this library in the web project you dont need the reference to the ejb project. after you can inject the ejb session bean by declaring the Remote interface and use this annotation: `@EJB(lookup ="JNDI_SESSIONBEAN_NAME")`

Comment: Still not working. I don't know what to do. I added some more information to the question. Could you take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have added the library in the ear project?

Comment: Yes I have. In the classpath. I don't know where to put it otherwise. I also made sure that in the packaging of the ejb module the jar of the library is included (at least, it should be). But it's still not working.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. Apparently the persistence.xml does matter in this problem. I added a persistence unit in the library and removed the one from the ejb module and after some restarting, undeploying and deploying it worked. Thanks for you help!